# Why does puppet module postgresql produce this error not found in the catalog

Tags: postgresql, puppet

I am using the puppet module postgresql from https://forge.puppet.com/modules/puppetlabs/postgresql/7.5.0 and in hiera have the following declared

```
postgresql::server::pg_hba_rules:
  "allow_subnet_1”:
    description: 'Allow subnet 1'
    type: 'host'
    address: ’10.10.56.0/24'
    database: 'foreman'
    user: 'foreman'
    auth_method: 'md5'
    order: '201'
```

Which produces the following warning,

```
Warning: /Stage[main]/Postgresql::Server/Postgresql::Server::Pg_hba_rule[allow1]/Concat::Fragment[pg_hba_rule_allow1]/Concat_fragment[pg_hba_rule_allow1]: Target Concat_file with path of /var/lib/pgsql/14/data/pg_hba.conf not found in the catalog
```

There is an attempt to create a hba rule then failes with "not found in the catalog” - can I get help to why doesn't work as expected?

I can provide more logs if needed.

Thanks

Comment: Hiera data does not produce *anything* (including errors) by itself.  What is the Puppet DSL code involved?  Is there any other Hiera data involved?  As a [mre], please.

Comment: The only Puppet code in the manifest is

include postgresql::server

In hiera I included this and the file resource was updated

postgresql::globals:
  manage_pg_hba_conf: 'true'
  pg_hba_conf_path: '/var/lib/pgsql/14/data/pg_hba.conf'

Comment: @ssaini could you let me know how to fixed this issue? I have the same problem.

Comment: @Maryam see my answer below I just added

Answer (score 1):

This worked.

To add rules:

```
postgresql::globals:
  manage_pg_hba_conf: 'true'

postgresql::server::pg_hba_conf_path: "/nfs/pgsql/data/%{hiera('postgresql::globals::version')}/pg_hba.conf"
#postgresql::server::manage_pg_hba_conf: true

postgresql::server::pg_hba_rules:
  "Allow xxx":
    description: 'Allow trusted connection for the xxx server.'
    type: 'host'
    database: 'all'
    user: 'postgres'
    address: '10.10.10.1/32'
    auth_method: 'trust'
  "Allow xxx1":
    description: 'Allow trusted connections from the monitoring host (xxx1).'
    type: 'host'
    database: 'postgres'
    user: 'nagios'
    address: '10.10.11.1/32'
    auth_method: 'trust'
```

Comment: adding   manage_pg_hba_conf: 'true' worked for me, thanks!